# Vue method call from v-for v-if combination not returning value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have this code in my html that does a v-for loop over an array and then for each entry call a method with a parameter using a v-if to only show the option tag is it returns true.

Here is the html code snippet portion:

```
<template v-for="a in agencies">
<option v-if="agencyCk(a) === true" :value="a">${a}</option>
</template>
```

Here is the method from the Vue script area:

```
agencyCk: function(agency) {
        // checked object keys for matching name
        if (Object.keys(st.fullAgency).find(function(k) {
            // if name matches agency
            if (k === agency) {
                var obj = st.fullAgency[k];
                // loops through an array for each value
                for (h in st.hosts) {
                    // if value matches object key's value
                    if (link === st.hosts[h]) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

As it is right now, it seems to return all as false.

Comment: Well? Are they supposed to be not all false? Having a [MCVE] would help here.

Comment: No some are true.  And when I put a console.log state above the return true with some phrase it posts that to the console for the one's that are true.  But I can't seem to it to show the <option></option> aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `agencyCk` function didn't explicitly return anything. So the return value of the function would be `undefined` which is interpreted as false.

To see why, have a closer look at the `if` statement, it basically boils down to something like this:

`if (Object.keys(...).find(...));`

It has no body. The return statements you wrote is for the `find` function not for the `agencyCk` function.

I think what you want is something like:

`return Object.keys(...).find(...) != undefined`